# imap_mail_move and append to subject

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to take an email received in an outlook inbox and conditionally move it from the folder it's currently in to a different folder. Currently, the code is as below:

```
$imap = imap_open($mailserver, $mailusr, $mailpass) or die("Connection Error");
$message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m){
....
 if(!$merr && $hasusable>0){  
       imap_mail_move($imap, $m, 'INBOX/Processor/inProcess'); }
 else{ imap_mail_move($imap, $m, 'INBOX/Processor/Failed'); }
```

i'd like to edit this to also conditionally append something to the subject line. e.g.

```
 if(!$merr && $hasusable>0){  
       if($isexplicit){
             [code to append XXXXX to subject line]
       }
       imap_mail_move($imap, $m, 'INBOX/Processor/inProcess'); 
 }
 else{ imap_mail_move($imap, $m, 'INBOX/Processor/Failed'); }
```

any ideas?

i'm pretty sure that this can be done with imap_append, but it's not clear to me how, and that seems like it deletes and recreates the initial email, and which might screw up the $m iterations

Comment: Any change to the message requires it to be a new message, which means you'd have to download it, change it, and append it to the new folder, then mark it for deletion from the source folder.  If you don't 'expunge' right away, the message ids won't shift.

Comment: that's less ideal, but i'm already downloading the message anyway (

    $header = imap_header($imap, $m);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $m);
and in an array:
$attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($imap, $m, $i+1);
) so i guess it's not such a big deal. is there a simple way to duplicate everything and just change the subject

Comment: Does it need to be (easily) user visible?  You could use IMAP Flags, which doesn't require re-uploading the message.

Comment: the actual subject line has to change since it searched for later in the inProcess folder by a different script

Comment: A script could check the flags in lieu of checking the subject.  That would be a lot more efficient.  I don't know the PHP Mail handling libraries enough to know how easy it would be to check the subject; I am trying to provide in-protocol libraries.

Comment: i can't change the other script.

Comment: i found a way of handling the requirement without modifying the subject. still i'd like to know how to:
1. copy the message and all of its contents, 2. modify the subject line of the header, 3. append the modified message into a new outlook folder
. if anyone knows of simple code for doing that, please let me know